# Applying linked stylesheets to document dynamically - add all, or add/remove dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, requirejs

I am using RequireJS to load stylesheets in an SPA, and then applying the stylesheets dynamically to whatever view the user sees. I am pretty much a web newb and I don't know if it makes sense to dynamically both add and remove stylesheets depending on the view, or should I just add all stylesheets to the document when the application starts up?

I assume in some cases, stylesheets might overlap, i.e. applying different parameters to the same .classes, etc. So surely in some cases it makes sense to remove a stylesheet from the document and add another.

Since this is an SPA, it should be the same document object throughout the application lifecycle, so I can't depend on a page reload to remove stylesheets - I will have to add and remove them explicitly.

Secondly, if I have loaded a CSS file with the Require-CSS* plugin like so:

```
define(['css!my_stylesheet_path'],function(sss){

 //how do I apply the stylesheet 'sss' to the document?  <<<<

});
```

I hope this question makes sense.

*https://github.com/guybedford/require-css

Answer (score 1):

Include you stylesheets in the main document itself.

If you are afraid that classes may repeat thus the styles might get over ridden. One of the ways to eradicate this is, give a unique parent id to your each template and append styles keeping this id followed by class, then you can be sure that these styles will never be over ridden as id is unique.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it does make sense to do that  considering your system environment and requirements specified, you should look into asynchronously loading assets, such as the famous google-analytic s code. You can load external style-sheets using Javascript.

**JavaScript:**

```
(function(){
  var styles = document.createElement('link');
  styles.rel = 'stylesheet';
  styles.type = 'text/css';
  styles.media = 'screen';
  styles.href = 'path/to/css/file';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styles);
})();
```

Lines 1 and 7 create a new scope for variables such that local variables do not collide or override with globally scoped variables. It isn't necessary just a best practice. This solution also assumes you have a `<head>` tag in your `html`.

To remove or edit a stylesheet you can give every stylesheet an id attribute and access it with this:

```
document.getElementById('styleid')
```

And then you can change the href attribute:

```
document.getElementById('styleid').setAttribute("href", "newfilename.css");
```

Or you can remove the complete tag:

```
var styletorem = document.getElementById('styleid');

styletorem.parentNode.removeChild(styletorem)
```

Check the link out for further reading :
[Add Rules To Stylesheet](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets)

Comment: thanks - so my next question is - as I mentioned - my stylesheets are now located on the front-end not on the server, because I have "required" them with RequireJS. So how to do I link to a JavaScript runtime object instead of a .css file on the server?

Comment: Check on dynamic JavaScript insertion in the link: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

Comment: read this - you will learn something about applying CSS from JS memory http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Comment: ```javascript: var sheet = document.createElement('style');   sheet.innerHTML = "div {border: 2px solid black; background-color: blue;}";                                                                document.body.appendChild(sheet); ```

Comment: it took me an hour to find an example of truly adding something dynamically; something that doesn't use AJAX underneath.

Comment: SPA is a very dynamic environment, and it's trivial that you wouldn't like to import all the style-sheets in the head section,and you would want them dynamically loaded, I took your codes down, will use it later on, if needed, cheers.

Comment: yes, 5 stylesheets in the <head> means 5 stylesheets that must load synchronously (in order) before your application does, it is bad. this is why we use things like RequireJS, afterall.

Comment: Well, I have never used Requirejs before, now checking the documents, it can be used for Node too! and it's compatible with IE6....

Comment: webpack and browserify are more modern, but RequireJS is quite nice too; you have to keep in mind that ES6 is coming soon, which will make the first 2 more useful